# How to enable my application to automatically perform the search when the user select a Json value in an auto complete search

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

i am implementing an auto complete search , currently my senario works as following:-
1. the user insert part of the search critiria.
2. select the intended Json value.
3. click on the ajax.Beginform search button.

but what i want to do is:-
1. the user insert part of the search critiria.
2. select the intended Json value.
3.Then the system automatically perform the search without the need to click on the search button (same as in google, yahoo,etc search engines).
here is my code:-
the quicksearch action method:-

```
public ActionResult QuickSearch(string term) 
       { 
                                 var users = entities1.Users 
               .Where(e => e.UserID.Contains(term)) 
               .Select(r => new {value = r.UserID }); 
            return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 

       }
```

and on the view i have the following code:-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "User", new AjaxOptions 
{ 
    HttpMethod = "POST", 
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    UpdateTargetId = "searchResults", 
   LoadingElementId = "progress" 
})) 
{ 

     <input type="text" name="q" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("QuickSearch", "User")" /> 
     <input type="hidden" name="classid" value="@ViewBag.classid"/> 



     <input type="submit" value="Search" /> 
}
```

the auto complete script:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
var target = $(this);
target.autocomplete({ source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source") });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try subscribing to the [.select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) event and manually trigger the form submission:

```
target.autocomplete({ 
    source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"),
    select: function(event, ui) { 
        $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    }
});
```